# How to capture desktop screen and draw in on window in linux

Tags: linux, window, capture, bitblt

I am new to linux and i need port my windows program to linux and need help at the following.

1. I need to capture the screen.
2. I need to create a window without borders and title which covers the whole screen.
3. I need to draw the captures screen on that window.
4. I need to alpha blend a black picture over the window at XX% opacity.

All this was done easily with GetDC(NULL), BitBlt() and AlphaBlend() on windows.

Linux looks very hard when coming to such simple programs to do.

Comment: Some links on stackoverflow that all talks about screen capturing but none of them gives a solution to my question.

Answer (score 4):

For Linux; you can always look at the source for [scrot](http://scrot.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.8-9/files.html) -- a small and simple screenshot program.